# React Issue - Value in Props not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hope you're doing well. I am reaching out because I am having a problem with rendering a property of props not being recognized. I am attempting to pull a value out of one component, into another component (the home component - where state is set from which the props are passed) and then pass that (again, in this case state) into another component and I am getting the error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'CustomerJoin').`

To be a little more specific here:

- Again, there are three components at play here. One is the home component, which has two different children. In one of these components a user selects and item in a list. The item that is listed is set in state in the parent component, and then it is passed into the component that is having the issue.
- The state setting is in the home component is always managed by passing a function into the two children which manages those conditions. Obvioulsy, therefore, state is set in the parent component so it can be then handed down to children in props and employed there.

**Below is the relevant code for the home component**

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { activeComponent: window.location.pathname.replace('/',''), activeCustomer: null, activeFlight: null, activeContact: null, activeEmail: null}
  }

  setActiveCustomer = (selectedCustomer) => {
    this.setState({activeCustomer: selectedCustomer})
    console.log('active customer - Home Component: ', selectedCustomer)
  }

  setComponent = (component) => {
    this.setState({activeComponent: component})
  }

  renderComponent() {
    const path = this.state.activeComponent;
    if(path === 'CreateContacts')
    {
      return <CreateCustomer activeCustomer={this.state.activeCustomer}/>
    } else if (path === 'Customers') {
      return <Customers setActiveCustomer={this.setActiveCustomer}/>
    } else if (path.substring(0, path.indexOf('/')) === 'Customer') {
      return <CustomerProfilePage activeCustomer={this.state.activeCustomer} setComponent={this.setComponent} setActiveCustomer={this.setActiveCustomer} setActiveContact={this.setActiveContact}/>
    } else if (path === 'CreateContact'){
      return <CreateContact activeCustomer={this.state.activeCustomer} setComponent={this.setComponent} activeContact={this.state.activeContact}/>
    } else if (path === 'Flights'){
      return <Flights setFlight={this.setFlight} setComponent={this.setComponent}/>
    } else if (path === 'Flights/FlightConfiguration') {
      return <FlightPage activeFlight={this.state.activeFlight} setComponent={this.setComponent} setActiveEmail={this.setActiveEmail}/>
    } else if (path === 'EmailConfiguration'){
      return <EmailConfiguration activeFlight={this.state.activeFlight} activeEmail={this.state.activeEmail}/>
    }
    return <HomeComponent/>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col'>
          <Sidebar/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='component-container grey rounded-corners padding'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col'>
            {this.renderComponent()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}



**Customer Profile Component.**

- This is the component where the error is occurring. The error is occurring in the beginning of the render component.


`import React from 'react';
import HeaderComponent from '../HelperComponents/ComponentHeaders'
import { removeContact, getListOfContacts } from '../../Library/API_CALLS'

export default class CustomerProfilePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { component: 'Customer Profile Page', activeCustomer: this.props.activeCustomer, activeContactList:[] }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getContactList()
    }

    getContactList = () => {
        getListOfContacts(this.props.activeCustomer.CustomerId)
            .then((this.getContactListSuccess))
            .catch((this.getContactListError))
    }

    getContactListSuccess = (response) => {
        this.setState({activeContactList: response})
    }

    getContactListError = (returnedError) => {
        console.log('Error Message: ', returnedError)
    }

    deleteContact = (deleteContact) => {
        removeContact(deleteContact.ContactId);
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const indexOfContact = prevState.activeContactList.findIndex(
                contact => contact.Email === deleteContact.Email);
                const newContactList = [...prevState.activeContactList];
                if(indexOfContact >= 0) newContactList.splite(indexOfContact, 1);
                return {activeContactList: newContactList}
        });
    }

    editContact = (contact) => {
        this.props.setActiveContact(contact)
        this.setComponent()
    }

    editContactButton = () => {
        this.props.setComponent('CreateContacts')
    }

    setComponent = () => {
        this.props.setComponent('CreateContacts')
        this.props.setActiveCustomer(this.props.activeCustomer)
    }

    convertDate = (entryDate) => {
        let returnDate = new Date(entryDate).getFullYear()
        return returnDate
    }

    buildContactTable(customerContactList, editContact){
        const contactRow = customerContactList.map(contact => {
            return <tr><td><span>{contact.FirstName + ' ' + contact.LastName}</span></td><td>{contact.Email}</td><td>{contact.PhoneNumber}</td><td><button className='rounded-corners contact-button' onClick={function(){editContact(contact)}}>Edit</button><button className='red rounded-corners contact-button' onClick={() => this.deleteContact(contact)}> Delete</button></td></tr>
        })

        return(
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col'>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr className='green'>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Phone</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {contactRow}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render(){
        const renderedDate = this.convertDate(this.state.activeCustomer.CustomerJoin)
        const contactList = this.state.activeContactList;
        return(
            <div className={this.state.component}>
                <HeaderComponent component={this.state.component} activeCustomer={this.props.activeCustomer.CustomerName}/>
                <div className='Component-Body'>
                    <div className='Component-Element-Container'>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col'>
                                <div className='center Component-Header-Text green'>
                                    <h3>{this.props.activeCustomer.CustomerName}</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col'>
                                This Organization's profile is below
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col'>
                                <b>Organization Detail:</b>
                                <div className='center'>
                                    <button className='rounded-corners customer-profile-button' onClick={this.setComponent}>Edit Customer</button> <button onClick={this.setComponent} className='rounded-corners customer-profile-button'>Add Contact</button> <button className='red rounded-corners customer-profile-button'> Delete Customer</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col'>
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Hello</th>
                                            <th>Contact</th>
                                            <th>Country</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Organization Name:</b> {this.props.activeCustomer.CustomerName}</td>
                                            <td><b>Phone: </b></td>
                                            <td><b>Fax: </b></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Primary Contact: </b></td>
                                            <td><b></b></td>
                                            <td><b></b></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Default Language: </b></td>
                                            <td><b>Fiscal Year Starts: </b></td>
                                            <td><b>Newsletter?: </b></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Customer Street:</b>{this.props.activeCustomer.CustomerStreet1}</td>
                                            <td><b>Customer Street 2: </b></td>
                                            <td><b>City: </b>{this.props.activeCustomer.CustomerCity}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Customer State: </b>{this.props.activeCustomer.CustomerCity}</td>
                                            <td><b>Customer Acquisition Date: </b>{renderedDate}</td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Created By: </b></td>
                                            <td><b>Modified By: </b></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='Component-Element-Container'>
                        {contactList.length > 0 ? this.buildContactTable(contactList, this.editContact) : null}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}`
```

```
import React from 'react';
import HeaderComponent from '../HelperComponents/ComponentHeaders'
import {getCustomers} from '../../Library/API_CALLS'

export default class Customers extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { component: 'Customers', customerList: [], firstPage: 0, lastPage: 5}
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
        //There is presently no way to set the state for active customer in this component.
        //This is because the entire customer set of information is not required on this page.
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getListOfCustomers();
    }

    getListOfCustomers = () => {
        getCustomers()
            .then((this.getCustomersListSuccess))
            .catch((this.getContactListError))
    }

    getCustomersListSuccess = (returnedCustomerList) => {
        this.setState({customerList: returnedCustomerList})
    }

    getContactListError = (error) => {
        console.log(error)
    }

    setCustomer = (customer) => {
        console.log('Customer List Component: ', customer)
        this.props.setActiveCustomer(customer)
    }

    renderCustomerRow = (customer) => {
        let customerCard = customer
        return(
            <div className='Component-Element-Container' onClick={() => this.setCustomer(customerCard)} key={customer.CustomerId}>
                <a href={`/Customer/${customer.CustomerName.replace(/\s/g, '')}`}><h3>{customer.CustomerName}</h3></a>
                <p>{customer.CustomerStreet1}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.manageList()
    }

    manageList(){
        let lowIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.customerList.length - 5);
        let highIndex = lowIndex + 5;
        if(lowIndex <= 0){
            lowIndex = 0
            highIndex = 5
        }
        this.setState({firstPage: lowIndex, lastPage: highIndex})

        //Since we're working on this just as a prototype, we have configured it in such a way that the pages will randomly flip and return
        //a positive value that is within the list of pages.

        //in a full blown application, this would be managed systematically.
    }
    render(){
        const CustomerList = this.state.customerList.slice(this.state.firstPage,this.state.lastPage)
        return(
            <div className='Customers'>
                <HeaderComponent component={this.state.component}/>
                <div className='Component-Body'>
                    {CustomerList.length > 0 ? CustomerList.map(this.renderCustomerRow) : <div>No number</div>}
                    <div className='component-element-container'>
                        <div className='center'>
                                <button className='green forward-button' id='forward-button'onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Click</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }}
```

Comment: I'd like to bump this question if I could. I'm looking for a little help here.